# How to solve this problem "permission denied”, when I start `docker compose up`?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When I just run docker build, I don't have any problems.

But, when I start with `docker-compose up` :

```
Cannot start service server: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: permission denied: unknown
```

Dockerfile

```
...

ENV CGO_ENABLED=0
ENV GO111MODULE=on
ENV GOFLAGS=-mod=vendor

RUN dep ensure

RUN go mod vendor
RUN go mod download
RUN go mod verify

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT  ["/go/src/github.com/project/module"]
```

docker-compose.yaml

```
 ...
  server:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: service.dockerfile
    platform: linux
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### About docker permissions

#### Proper solution

1. You need to have all reqiured permissions for volumes
2. Add your user to docker group. More info here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/

#### Fast and bad solution

Run docker-compose with sudo or as a root: `sudo docker-compose -f ... up`

---

### The OCI error:

But your problem is not with permisisons, it is with a non-existing program:

```
ENTRYPOINT  ["/go/src/github.com/project/module"]
```

Is `/go/src/github.com/project/module` program executable binary with permissions to execute it?

Answer (score 2):

My problem was similar but was with the entrypoint.sh file. What i forgot was to change the permession for this file. "Newbie things :D"

I had this in my file: `ENTRYPOINT ["/home/app/web/entrypoint.prod.sh"]` and the given below command i used to solve the issue.

```
chmod +x path-to-file/entrypoint.prod.sh
```